# How to merge two tables and then tabulate counts in one step using data.table

Tags: r, merge, data.table

```
library(data.table)
table1 <- data.table(id1 = c(1324, 2324, 29, 29, 1010, 1010),
                     type = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1),
                     class = c("A",  "A", "B", "D", "D", "A"),
                     number = c(1, 98, 100, 100, 70, 70))
table2 <- data.table(id2 = c(1998, 1998, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2010, 2012, 2012),
                     type = c(1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1),
                     class = c("D", "A", "D", "D", "A", "B", "A", "A"),
                     min_number = c(34, 0, 20, 45, 5, 23, 1, 1),
                     max_number = c(50, 100, 100, 100, 100, 9, 10, 100))
> table1
    id1 type class number
1: 1324    1     A      1
2: 2324    1     A     98
3:   29    2     B    100
4:   29    1     D    100
5: 1010    1     D     70
6: 1010    1     A     70
> table2
    id2 type class min_number max_number
1: 1998    1     D         34         50
2: 1998    1     A          0        100
3: 2000    3     D         20        100
4: 2000    1     D         45        100
5: 2000    1     A          5        100
6: 2010    5     B         23          9
7: 2012    1     A          1         10
8: 2012    1     A          1        100
```

**Step 1.** I have two tables, and I would like to merge them based on `type`, `class`, and whether `number` lies between `min_number` and `max_number`.

```
merged <- table2[table1, on = c("type", "class", "max_number >= number", "min_number <= number")]
> merged
     id2 type class min_number max_number  id1
 1: 1998    1     A          1          1 1324
 2: 2012    1     A          1          1 1324
 3: 2012    1     A          1          1 1324
 4: 1998    1     A         98         98 2324
 5: 2000    1     A         98         98 2324
 6: 2012    1     A         98         98 2324
 7:   NA    2     B        100        100   29
 8: 2000    1     D        100        100   29
 9: 2000    1     D         70         70 1010
10: 1998    1     A         70         70 1010
11: 2000    1     A         70         70 1010
12: 2012    1     A         70         70 1010
```

**Step 2.** Then for each `class`, I would like to count how many unique `id1`s there are and how many unique `id2`s there are. The final desired output is this:

```
library(dplyr)
count_merged <- merged %>% group_by(class) %>% 
  summarise(n_id2 = n_distinct(id2[!is.na(id2)]),
            n_id1 = n_distinct(id1))
> count_merged
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  class n_id2 n_id1
  <chr> <int> <int>
1 A         3     3
2 B         0     1
3 D         1     2
```

My question: is there a faster way of doing this? If `table1` and `table2` have hundreds of thousands of rows, then it is extremely slow to do merge the two tables in **Step 1**. Is there a way to obtain the counts without merging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pure `data.table` option

```
table2[
  table1,
  on = c("type", "class", "max_number >= number", "min_number <= number"),
  mult = "first"
][,
  lapply(.SD, uniqueN, na.rm = TRUE),
  class,
  .SDcols = patterns("^id")
]
```

which gives

```
   class id2 id1
1:     A   1   3
2:     B   0   1
3:     D   1   2
```

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table::uniqueN`:

```
merged[,.(nid2=uniqueN(id2,na.rm=T),nid1=uniqueN(id1)),class]

#    class  nid2  nid1
#   <char> <int> <int>
#1:      A     3     3
#2:      B     0     1
#3:      D     1     2
```

Performance comparison:

```
Unit: microseconds
  expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
 dplyr 5249.1 5955.15 8626.139 6381.50 8118.95 79625.4   100
    dt  675.3  876.75 1122.979  981.65 1297.50  2649.8   100
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to avoid merging the two tables somehow and get the counts directly? The issue I have is that I can't even get the `merged` table because my `table1` and `table2` are very large (many rows).

Comment: I overlooked the merge problem ;) . I see no easy way around except running it with more RAM.